# What is the order of execution of the return statements for saving the form data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
def issuebook_view(request):
    form=forms.IssuedBookForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        #now this form have data from html
        form=forms.IssuedBookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj=models.IssuedBook()
            obj.enrollment=request.POST.get('enrollment2')
            obj.isbn=request.POST.get('isbn2')
            bk = models.Book.objects.get(isbn = obj.isbn)
            if bk.available_copies == 0:
                return render(request,'library/booksover.html')
            if bk.available_copies > 0:
                bk.available_copies = bk.available_copies - 1
                bk.save()
            obj.save()
            return render(request,'library/bookissued.html')
    return render(request,'library/issuebook.html',{'form':form})
```

I am new to Django and finding it difficult to understand the order of execution of the return statements in the above function to save the form data. Can anyone explain the order of execution of the execution of the return statements.As per my understanding i think first the last return render statement with the form template is run and then the execution shifts back upwards and processes the rest of code from form.is_valid. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you hit a `return` it leaves the function completely. There is no "back upwards".

Comment: @KlausD. can you please elaborate how the function executes then

Comment: `bk.save()` is conditional on `bk.available_copies > 0` whereas `obj.save()` is unconditional.  A differernt case when  both are unconditional, one has to save a new object to give it a `pk` and you can't use it as a ForeignKey in another object until it has got its `pk`. So, save the new object first before updating a ForeignKey that refers to it.